# Javascript input form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, pug

I have this datepicker function:

```
!!!5
html
  head
    link(type='text/css', href='http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css',  rel='stylesheet')
script(src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js', type='text/javascript')
script(src='http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js', type='text/javascript')
script
  $(function() {
    $.datepicker.setDefaults(
      $.extend($.datepicker.regional[""])
    );
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
  });
```

I want to send the result of the chosen date with a input form.

```
input#datepicker(type='text')
```

I get the input field and can choose dates and so forth, but I can't seem to receive/transfer it to my other .js file.

How can I package the result into a form (with the value)? With other values I just do something like this:

```
form(action="/registerActivity", method="post")
  select(name = "item[activity]")
    each point in points
      option(value=point.Activity) #{point.Activity}

  select(name ="item[participant]")
    option(value='testValue') Just a Option

  input#datepicker(type='text', name="item[date]")
  input(type="submit", value="Registrer participant")
```

And this is received like this:

```
registerActivity: function(req,res) {
  var item = req.body.item;
  newActivity = new activity();
  newActivity.activityName = item.activity;
  newActivity.acitivtyParticipant = item.participant;
  newActivity.acitivtyDate = item.date;
  newActivity.save(function savedActivity(err){
    if(err) {
      throw err;
    }
  });
  res.redirect('/');
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not showing the entire code but its possible you're missing a name attribute by the look of it. That's what req.body looks for.

so in jade it would be

```
input#datepicker(type='text', name='yourname')
```

Comment: can u edit ur ques. or throw up a fiddle so I can see the entire jade view please.

Comment: change it to just a string instead of grabbing from the item object so change it to just name="mydate" or something like that and console.log the req.body and see if you see the value.

Comment: but you get values from the other inputs? Or is the entire body undefined.

Comment: yes, tried to console.log every value now. It is just the date that does not transfer.

Comment: that seems crazy odd. give me a min and I'll fire up a node project using ur source, you have my full curiosity now as this makes little sense lol.

Comment: oh yes, it seems to work with the String way after all! Successfully got the date now. I will try to get it transferred to DB also. Thanks for helping!

Comment: you're welcome vote or mark as answer if u would please. btw my .02 is that with jade you'll run into silly stuff like this. just a heads up. I started using ejs because of these very sorts of things. jade is cool but my patience couldn't handle having a tab in wrong place. ha ha.